# error SVC-SOCRECV & marklogic gives a code 408 when I sent a http-post

Tags: marklogic

I give a http-post request with 30, sometimes marklogic response error with code 408 while execute this http-post call. I am just so wired what does the 408 means?

I search some document on marklogic community, and I recognized some information https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/messages/SVC-en/SVC-SOCRECV, but I still want to know why 408.

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses

> **408 Request Timeout**
>
> This response is sent on an idle connection by some servers, even without any previous request by the client. It means that the server would like to shut down this unused connection. This response is used much more since some browsers, like Chrome, Firefox 27+, or IE9, use HTTP pre-connection mechanisms to speed up surfing. Also note that some servers merely shut down the connection without sending this message.